# Sort point character first

Tags: bash, sorting

I would like to sort a list of file names using sort.
For instance:

```
file.ext
file1.ext
z_file2.ext
```

Using sort, I get

```
file1.ext
file.ext
z_file2.ext
```

How can I do so that *file.* is sorted before *fileXXXX.* ?

Comment: Try running the command with `LC_ALL=C`.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't help

Comment: What shell, OS, `sort` version? Any hidden characters in the filenames?

Comment: bash, fedora 22, sort (GNU coreutils) 8.23, no hidden character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, your problem is that your locale produces an odd sort order. Setting the locale to C for the sort should fix the problem:

```
LC_ALL=C sort
```

For a more precise fix, assuming you want to use locale-aware collation order but still separate the sort key at the extension, specify `.` as the field delimiter and use two sort keys:

```
sort -t. -k1,1 -k2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -d option

From manpage:

> `-d, --dictionary-order   consider only blanks and alphanumeric characters`

```
$ cat toto
file.ext
file1.ext
z_file2.ext

$ sort -d toto
file1.ext
file.ext
z_file2.ext
```

Comment: it doesn't work, as you write file1.ext is before file.ext

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the filenames from the digits, sort them accordingly and merge back

```
$ sed -r 's/([0-9]*)\./ &/' file | sort -k1,1 -k2n | sed 's/ //'
file.ext
file1.ext
z_file2.ext
z_file11.ext
```